# Natural numbers for which $n!+1$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I was given the following problem:

Generate a sequence of n consecutive composite numbers.

The answer was $$(n+1)!+2,(n+1)!+3,(n+1)!+4,...,(n+1)!+n+1$$

However I was thinking if we could simplify the answer a bit by knowing for which numbers $n!+1$ is prime or composite.

By putting values I got that it is prime for $n=1,2,3,11$

How do I proceed?

Comment: The sequence of $n$ for which $n!+1$ is prime is [A002981](https://oeis.org/A002981).  It is not known whether that is infinite or not.